# Visual Studio 2013 issue with missing Platform Toolset v14

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have Visual Studio installed on my machine, the 2012, 2013 and 2015 versions to be precise. 2012 and 2013 are the 'professional' versions whilst 2015 is, for the time being the 'community' version.

Soon after I installed the 2015 version, the 2013 version's default platform toolset has switched to v140, to which VS has so elected to tell me isn't installed on my machine.

I am going to assume that it should've been installed with the 2015 version of Visual Studio? Should it have come with the instalation? Or is it because I'm using a Community Version this time the reason why it isn't installed?

Also, I have a lot of projects using older platform toolsets that cannot be built using this non-existant toolset. Nothing a reversion to an older toolset can fix, mind you, but should I go about acquiring the v140 platform toolset? And if so, how is this done?